# Multiple Meta-Regression of Proportions

Tags: proportion, meta-regression, metafor

I am conducting a multiple meta-regression of proportions and was hoping that I could get some help. Outcome variable is complications rates (logit transformed) and moderators are publication year and material type.  When I do the following:

```r
metareg.yearmaterial = rma(yi, vi, data=ies.logit, 
    mods=year + material, method="REML")
print(metareg.yearmaterial)
```

This is my output:

```r
Mixed-Effects Model (k = 38; tau^2 estimator: REML)

tau^2 (estimated amount of residual heterogeneity):     0.8901 (SE = 0.2975)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):             0.9435
I^2 (residual heterogeneity / unaccounted variability): 82.64%
H^2 (unaccounted variability / sampling variability):   5.76
R^2 (amount of heterogeneity accounted for):            10.96%

Test for Residual Heterogeneity:
QE(df = 36) = 131.2970, p-val < .0001

Test of Moderators (coefficient 2):
QM(df = 1) = 5.4755, p-val = 0.0193

Model Results:
          estimate       se     zval    pval      ci.lb     ci.ub    
intrcpt  -103.1225  43.5243  -2.3693  0.0178  -188.4285  -17.8164  * 
mods        1.0506   0.0216   2.3400  0.0193     0.0082    0.0930  *
```

2 Questions:

1. How do I make it so that I can see coefficients for each of the moderators separately?
2. On the regression coefficients, just to confirm, since I am doing a logit transformation the coefficient would then imply that the two moderators would result in a 1.05 times increase in complication rates?

Comment: You need to use a formula: `mods = ~ year+material`.